# Drag and drop from a FileListBox out of the Delphi application

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I implemented a drag and drop option from windows explorer into my Delphi application.

Now, I need to make it so that when dragging a file from a FileListBox just like when windows explorer files are dragged into Gmail.

In the attached image it can be seen that for any location outside the application, a cursor is displayed indicating that this functionality is not allowed.

I researched a lot, but I still didn't get an updated solution. I am using Delphi 10.3.

Thanks for all the help!

[image]

Comment: You need to implement proper OLE drag and drop, specifically the [`IDataObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject) and [`IDropSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idropsource) interfaces, IIRC.

Comment: (Or you could use a third-party library that does that for you.)

Comment: To expand on this, you need to call [`DoDragDrop()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-dodragdrop) when you are ready to drag files from your `TFileListBox`, providing it with an [`IDataObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject) that contains (or can access) the list of filenames, in [`CF_HDROP`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cf_hdrop) format. Anders Melander's [Drag&Drop framework](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/) can handle these details for you (see the `TDropFileSource` class).

Comment: The development of the forementioned framework by Anders Melander was discontinued in 2010, use [The Drag and Drop Component Suite for Delphi](https://github.com/landrix/The-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite-for-Delphi) by Sven Harazim that's based on Melander's work.